How can I improve my TypeScript mongoose connection?
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { routes } from './routes'

class App {
    public express: express.Application

    public constructor() {
        this.express = express()
        this.middleware()
        this.database()
        this.routes()
    }

    public middleware(): void {
        this.express.use(express.json())
    }

    public async database() {
        try {
            mongoose.set("strictQuery", true)
            await mongoose.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/adsis-books')
            console.log("Connect database sucess")
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Cannot connect to database, error:', error)
        }
    }

    public routes(): void {
        this.express.use(routes)
    }
}

export default new App().express

I don't know if I can improve anything.

What is the question here?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
